# nginx 403 permission denied

Tags: macos, nginx

I am trying to setup a HLS server using nginx on OSX. The following conf file is giving me a `403 Permission Denied` Can someone tell me why that's happening? I tried changing the permissions of the folder using `chmod`. That didn't help either.

Conf file:

```
worker_processes  auto;
events {
worker_connections  1024;
}

RTMP configuration
rtmp {
server {
    listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
    chunk_size 4000;

    application show {
        live on;
        # Turn on HLS
        hls on;
        hls_path /Users/anil/hls/hls/;
        hls_fragment 3;
        hls_playlist_length 60;
        # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
        deny play all;
    }
}
}

http {
sendfile off;
tcp_nopush on;
#aio on;
directio 512;
default_type application/octet-stream;

server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
        # Disable cache
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';

        # CORS setup
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Range';

        # allow CORS preflight requests
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }

        types {
            application/dash+xml mpd;
            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
            video/mp2t ts;
        }

        root /Users/anil/hls;
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what cmod did you give?

Comment: Did you change the root directory from /usr/share/nginx/html? I had this same problem. Reverting back to the default path solved it for me, and I sent them an email.

Comment: @Jorg I tried chmod 777 to make sure everything was in order.

Comment: @ShawnicHedgehog I think my root directory is not in /usr/share/nginx/html. I installed it via brew. Could it be somewhere else?

Comment: It seems your default is /Users/anil/hls; I'm not sure if this is the default for Windows or not, probably is. I had a problem when the root directory was changed, but if this is not the case then I'm not sure, I had a similar idea to Jorg.

Comment: I am pretty sure that's where the issue is. What's the default location of root? I had changed it to point to the new location - /Users/anil/hls

Comment: Looking at this gist https://gist.github.com/nishantmodak/d08aae033775cb1a0f8a, it seems the root is in the nginx installation folder under in a /html folder. Might try that.

Comment: I fixed the issue. My location was in /usr/local/var/www . Made that change and it worked. Thanks guys